Issues Installing Snap Packages on Ubuntu 24.04
I’m running Ubuntu 24.04 and I’ve encountered some issues while trying to install applications using Snap. Here’s a summary of the problem:
I tried to install PhpStorm using apt and received the following message:
$ sudo apt install phpstorm
[sudo] password for amyr: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done

No apt package "phpstorm", but there is a snap with that name.
Try "snap install phpstorm"
E: Unable to locate package phpstorm

Next, I attempted to install it via Snap:
$ snap install phpstorm
error: snap "phpstorm" not found

I then ran snap refresh and snap search phpstorm, and the output indicated that PhpStorm is available:
$ snap search phpstorm
Name      Version   Publisher   Notes    Summary
phpstorm  2024.2.1  jetbrains✓  classic  PhpStorm

However, when I tried to install PhpStorm with:
$ sudo snap install phpstorm --classic
error: snap "phpstorm" not found

Interestingly, I was able to successfully install the hello-world snap!
My Snap setup is as follows:
snap    2.63.1+24.04
snapd   2.63.1+24.04
series  16
ubuntu  24.04
kernel  6.8.0-41-generic

It seems like there’s an issue with locating or accessing the PhpStorm snap and some other apps like Webstorm and... (which I tried to install from Snap Store too). Has anyone else encountered this problem or have any suggestions for resolving it?
Thanks in advance for your help!

you could try installing it using the Flatpak version instead. This Linux Made Simple article explains how alongside a short YT video

Please post your answer as a separate answer instead of adding "solved" in the question. Also please click the check beside your answer to mark it as accepted.

SOLVED: It seems it was just a connection issue. I tried to turn on a VPN (Windscribe) and it worked.
